# What's the difference between mustRunAfter and dependsOn in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, dependencies, task

Whether taskB mustRunAfter taskA, or taskB dependsOn taskA, it seems that taskA runs first, then taskB runs. What's the difference?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

For example:

```
tasks.create('a')

tasks.create('b').dependsOn('a')

tasks.create('c')

tasks.create('d').mustRunAfter('c')
```

- `dependsOn` - sets task dependencies. Executing `b` here would require that `a` be executed first.
- `mustRunAfter` - sets task ordering. Executing `d` does not require `c`. But, when both `c` and `d` are included, `c` will execute before `d`.

Comment: Does this mean `b.dependsOn(a)` doesn't add the outputs of `a` to the inputs of `b`? So `a` could be run without `b` running?

Comment: @AnthonyD973 No, the inputs in this example are not implicitly passed through. Gradle does have support for dependency inference based on inputs/outputs in other areas, though.

Answer (score 16):

Where possible, [declare task inputs instead of task dependencies](https://melix.github.io/blog/2021/10/gradle-quickie-dependson.html).  That said, expanding on [mkobit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42034855/150884)'s answer:

## Ordering and dependencies involving two tasks

### `mustRunAfter`

`mustRunAfter` controls the execution order of tasks explicitly specified on the command line, but doesn't create implicit dependencies on other tasks.  Given `taskA` and `taskB`:

**build.gradle.kts**

```kotlin
val taskA by tasks.registering {
    doLast {
        println("taskA")
    }
}

val taskB by tasks.registering {
    doLast {
        println("taskB")
    }
}

taskB {
    mustRunAfter(taskA)
}
```

then

- `gradle taskB taskA` executes `taskA` followed by `taskB`;
- `gradle taskA` executes `taskA` only;
- `gradle taskB` executes `taskB` only.

### `dependsOn`

`dependsOn` creates implicit dependencies on other tasks.  Given the same two tasks:

```kotlin
taskB {
    dependsOn(taskA)
}
```

then

- `gradle taskB` executes `taskA` followed by `taskB`;
- `gradle taskB taskA` executes `taskA` followed by `taskB`;
- `gradle taskA` executes `taskA` only.

## Ordering and dependencies involving three tasks

`mustRunAfter` and `dependsOn` accept an [*unordered* collection of tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskDependency.html).  Given:

```kotlin
val taskC by tasks.registering {
    doLast {
        println("taskC")
    }
}

taskC {
    dependsOn(taskA, taskB)
}
```

then `gradle taskC` executes `taskA` and `taskB` in no guaranteed order, followed by `taskC` (assuming no other `dependsOn` or `mustRunAfter` declarations).

**`mustRunAfter`** also controls the execution order between interdependent tasks that would otherwise have no guaranteed order.  Given:

```kotlin
taskB {
    mustRunAfter(taskA)
}
```

then `gradle taskC` executes `taskA` followed by `taskB` followed by `taskC`, but `gradle taskB` only runs `taskA` because taskB does not `dependOn(taskA)`.

## Other types of task dependency

- `taskA { finalizedBy(taskB) }` ensures `gradle taskA` executes `taskA` followed by `taskB`;
- `shouldRunAfter` provides weaker ordering guarantees than `mustRunAfter`, [useful for breaking cyclic dependencies and parallel task execution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36794787/150884).

## Further reading

Consult the Gradle documentation for more information on:

- [adding dependencies to tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:adding_dependencies_to_tasks)
- [ordering tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:ordering_tasks)
- [skipping tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:skipping_tasks)

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes they have the same effect. For example, if taskC dependsOn taskA and taskB, then it doesn't matter whether taskB dependsOn taskA or mustRunAfter it - when you run taskC, the order will be taskA, taskB, taskC.

But if taskC dependsOn taskB only, then there's a difference. If taskB dependsOn taskA, then it's the same as above - taskA, taskB, taskC. If taskB merely mustRunAfter taskA, then taskA doesn't run, and running taskC will run taskB, then taskC.

mustRunAfter really means *if taskA runs at all*, then taskB must run after it.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if order is important, it appears that you need both dependsOn and mustRunAfter. Here is an example of running two tasks, one (custom registered "importUnicodeFiles" task) that is in "this" project and one (predefined "run" task) that is in a sibling project named ":unicode":

```
tasks.register("rebuildUnicodeFiles") {
    description = "Force the rebuild of the `./src/main/resources/text` data"
    val make = project(":unicode").tasks["run"]
    val copy = tasks["importUnicodeFiles"]
    dependsOn(make)
    dependsOn(copy)
    copy.mustRunAfter(make)
}
```