# Can a Gradle task have dependsOn and mustRunAfter

Tags: gradle

Can I have a Gradle task where I can have both `dependsOn` and `mustRunAfter` to define the dependencies and the ordering?

```
tasks.register('MyTask') {
    dependsOn 'foo'
    dependsOn 'bar'
    dependsOn 'toy'
    
    tasks.findByName('bar').mustRunAfter('foo')
    tasks.findByName('toy').mustRunAfter('bar')
}
```

I want to run foo -> bar -> toy.

Are these two the same?

```
tasks.register('MyTask2') {
    dependsOn 'hello'
    tasks.findByName('MyTask2').mustRunAfter('hello')
}   


tasks.register('MyTask2') {
    mustRunAfter('hello')
}
```

Is this a correct approach? I tried going over [a few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36794690/what-is-the-difference-between-mustrunafter-and-shouldrunafter-in-task-ordering) [posts](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html), but couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To order tasks you can use `dependsOn` or `mustRunAfter`. But there is a big difference between them

> I want to run foo -> bar -> toy.

If you want to run a chain of tasks when you run one of them in the chain you need to use `dependsOn`:

```
tasks.register('MyTask') {
    // some logic is here
}    

// do not configure other tasks inside another task

tasks.findByName("bar").dependsOn("foo")
tasks.findByName("toy").dependsOn("bar")
```

The result will be as follows:

- when you run `toy`, `bar` and `foo` will be run
- when you run `bar`, `foo` will be run
- when you run `foo`, no other tasks will be run

> Are these two the same?

No, it's not the same thing.
This means that when you run `MyTask2`, `hello` will be run erlier:

```
tasks.register('MyTask2') {
    dependsOn 'hello'
    // tasks.findByName('MyTask2').mustRunAfter('hello')
}
```

This means that when you run `MyTask2`, nothing will be happen:

```
tasks.register('MyTask2') {
    mustRunAfter('hello')
}
```

But when you run `MyTask2` and `hello` together, `MyTask2` will be run only after `hello`.

There is an example that I posted on my [github](https://github.com/elimxim/so-gradle-mustrunafter-vs-dependson)